# Why is Heroku skipping precompile step in Rails 3.1 app?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm messing around with a rails 3.1 app and deploying to Heroku Cedar.

When pushing an app, Heroku skips over the precompile step without throwing an error:

```
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker
-----> Compiled slug size is 16.2MB
-----> Launching... done, v35
```

The last time I pushed to Heroku (maybe a month ago) it had no problem precompiling assets.

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.1.rc2', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', :branch => '3-1-stable'
```

UPDATE:

I was able to get Heroku to precompile by removing the following from application.rb:

```
 if defined?(Bundler)
   # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
   Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
   # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
   # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
 end
```

and replacing with:

```
# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets) if defined?(Bundler)
```

Comment: That seemed to work for me. The push to heroku still said there were errors, but the page loads correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sound conceiting, but did you make sure you create the Heroku app with -stack cedar?

Comment: `heroku stack
  aspen-mri-1.8.6
  bamboo-mri-1.9.2
  bamboo-ree-1.8.7
* cedar (beta)`

Answer (score 0):

You could also check to see that sprockets is enabled as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812295/heroku-is-not-pre-compiling-my-assets-to-prepare-my-app-for-asset-pipeline/7825006#7825006) when I was having the same problem.