# Heroku is not pre-compiling my assets to prepare my app for asset pipeline

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, mongoid, asset-pipeline

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my asset pipeline setup working with Heroku/Cedar using Rails 3.1.1

I've pushed my application and it launches successfully but there was no message that said "Preparing asset pipeline" and no static assets are being served up. No JS, CSS, or images are able to be found as there is no slug compilation time or runtime asset compilation being done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

They describe what should happen during deployment at this [link](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31) which I'll summarize below:

> With a Rails 3.1 application on Heroku Cedar when you git push heroku your assets will all be pre-compiled as part of the deploy process by using the rake task bundle exec rake assets:precompile.

Comment: just a minor point - If you've already precompiled your assets locally, committed to git and pushed to Heroku and a manifest file exists in public/assets then Heroku will NOT attempt to precompile your assets.

Comment: That is correct, but that wasn't the pre-compilation option I was looking for. This solution is to be used for wanting to compile assets at slug compilation time specifically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok so the solution was this:

I'm using mongoid which has you remove the 'rails/all' line as part of the configuration. As a result sprockets was not being loaded.

What you need to do with rails 3.1+ is also add `require "sprockets/railtie"` in application.rb so that sprockets are enabled. Boom, works.

This info can be found on the mongoid website [here](http://mongoid.org/docs/installation/configuration.html). This is useful to know for anyone who may not be loading the full 'rails/all' in application.rb, sprockets is obviously required for the asset pipeline to work.

Comment: good to know - you'd have thought this would have shown up running the app locally in production mode though.

Comment: You're right! Please read documentation carefully before doing anything Giovanni. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Wow, after looking for hours for what was wrong, I finally stumbled across this. You're a savior.

Comment: Added mongoid + mongodb to tags so it can be found more easily, cheers.

Comment: oh my god. thank you! i'm feeling like an idiot. i read that documentation over and over and still got owned. ugh.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this article on Rails 3.1 asset pipeline on Heroku - http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar. I reviewed it yesterday and picked up a good few hints from it and I've been running Rails 3.1 sites on Heroku for quite a while now.

Was this a new Rails 3.1 site or a site upgraded to Rails 3.1, things to check would be that the asset pipeline is enabled for production - by default Rails 3.1 uses

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

in application.rb. Are you using app/assets for your assets and not public/

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding to my question. I don't think I've touched that file, updating question with info.

Comment: To clarify, this is rails 3.1.1 and the pipeline works fine on local but doesn't compile when deploying to Heroku.

Comment: I just created a new app to verify and that setting exists.

Comment: did you try running it in production locally to see if you can get anymore insight?

Comment: Yeah everything is working as it should but its just that heroku isn't triggering that one stage of the deployment that is necessary. I also see that the assets rake tasks don't appear doing a heroku run rake -T but they do locally, very odd.

Comment: I've just created this dummy app (vanilla Rail3.1.1 with a single scaffolded model) https://github.com/johnbeynon/vanila311 and pushed it to heroku at http://glowing-stone-9665.herokuapp.com/marks and the pipeline is working.